# How can I resolve error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" with my macro?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My macro keeps failing at this point in my macro, where I'm filling in all the cells in a particular column with a formula reference the column next to it.

I have another nested IF formula in my macro that works fine. They do not rely on each other either. Any ideas?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Nurture"",RC[-1])),""New Producer Nurture"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WB FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS REM"",RC[-1])),""Event Promotion"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing OB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing Direct to Agent"",RC[-1])),""" & _
    "Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Info Email Response"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing IB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ZProgramsMatch"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Registration Support"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Web Contact Form Outreach"",RC[-1])),""General Mar" & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""General Product Inquiry"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""))))))))))))"
```

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to use `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: @braX I tried that, and now the macro just stops at that point. There is a yellow arrow pointing at line 4 in the above code

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your formula then. Carefully check your quotes and parenthesis.

Comment: The formula works fine when pasted into any cell in the column I need it in (and also works when I auto-fill the column after pasting it in to the first row)

Comment: The end of the second line of your formula is `...""General Mar` and the beginning of the 3rd line is `IF(ISNUMBER....` so the concatenation would be `....General MarIF(ISNUMBER....` which is not valid syntax i think?? Maybe you meant the end of the 2nd line to be `""General Marketing""," & _` ??

Comment: @garbb I didn't write it in VBA -- I recorded a macro of entering that formula in, and it did that itself. When I edit those lines to reflect the correct code, it gives me a syntax error, which is probably true since I don't know VBA

Comment: Maybe something goofy is happening with the record macro feature because it is a long formula? Just type in a formula to the cell manually, make sure it is working as you want, then paste it into some text editor, search and replace all `"` with `""` and then paste in into vba like this `ActiveCell.Formula = "<big long formula here>"` (it should be ok to have all on one line, you shouldn't need to split it into multiple lines.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it like this....

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Nurture"",RC[-1])),""New Producer Nurture""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WB FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS REM"",RC[-1])),""Event Promotion""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing OB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing Direct to Agent"",RC[-1])),""Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Info Email Response"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing IB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ZProgramsMatch"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Registration Support"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Web Contact Form Outreach"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
    "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""General Product Inquiry"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""))))))))))))"
```

Comment: To bring life full circle, I fixed everything, and now my personal macro workbook has disappeared entirely after saving. Well, at least I have part of it right here. It's just a macro away.